# Editing with Nano

Tags: command-line, text-editor, nano

Is it possible to edit an existing text file using only one line of command and Nano. For instance if I have a text file called "new.txt" and I want to write "HELLO WORLD" in it. Can I do like this:

```
nano new.txt "something that will make it to write in that file "HELLO WORLD"
```

That is, can I write in a file using Nano without explicitly opening it in Nano. Yet only add something after the command nano (like -w for write) and the file name in the terminal.

Comment: Do you want to append a line to the file? If yes, then you don't need nano at all and I'm happy to provide an answer. Or do you want to create a completely new file? Please [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: @gertvdijk: Yes I would add at into an existing file that is append it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `>>` in your shell. This is a way of [output redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) that will append to a file. In order to create the output, use the simple `echo`. E.g.

```
echo "Hello world." >> /path/to/file.txt
```

Alternatively, to create a new file (or to overwrite an existing one), use a single `>`, e.g.:

```
echo "Hello world." > /path/to/new/file.txt
```

One can use any command that create output to redirect it to a file like this. `echo` is just an example that outputs the argument(s) to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
cd /path/to/the/directory/where/filename.txt/is/located
echo "Hello World" >> filename.txt
```

`>>` - append lines to an existing file.If no such file was present then it automatically creates a new one.
`>`  - overwrites an existing file or create a new one and writes standard output.

Comment: to append a line you don't need nano like @gertvdijk said.